# Why doesn't wikipedia update their website UI

Tags: website-design

Ever since I started using Wikipedia, back in 2007, I don't think I have ever seen a major (or minor) change in their site’s look and feel.

Why don't they update their style to a more modern look? It doesn't necessarily look bad, but just like a snapshot of 2000 websites.

Comment: Don't fix what isn't broken.

Comment: Perhaps because hundreds of millions and even billions of people are familiar with it? `MediaWiki` (the platform Wikipedia is based on) offers a lot of customization features (including the way the wiki looks and feels) which many companies, institutions and single users use for their own wikis. Look what happened with Windows when the Metro UI was introduced? In order to prove my point here note the fact that Windows 10 added the option of using the Start menu again. One of the main reasons (for normal users probably the top one!) for the failure of Windows 8 was the change in the UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have their own reason for this case, and you could find their reason in this link [Why-doesnt-Wikipedia-innovate-with-regards-to-their-user-interface](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Wikipedia-innovate-with-regards-to-their-user-interface) and it will satisfied you for sure, because the answers come from the wiki's team :)

Comment: I think that answer it is pretty complete, but some information about this subject can be found too on their website, https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Design.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina wow, thank you for the additional information, glad to know about wiki's design process.

Comment: I'm glad this info is useful. In fact, they have a section about redesign proposals : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unsolicited_redesigns